# Use fetch instead of ajax with redux-observable

Tags: ajax, redux, rxjs5, isomorphic-fetch-api, redux-observable

In `redux-observable` is it possible to use [isomporphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) instead of [Rx.DOM.ajax](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

(Note: `RX.DOM.ajax` is from RxJS **v4**, and doesn't work with `redux-observable` which requires [RxJS **v5**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src). The equivalent in v5 is [`Rx.Observable.ajax`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.js.html) or `import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/ajax';`)

It is indeed possible to use `fetch()` as well as any other AJAX API; though some adapt easier than others!

The `fetch()` API returns a `Promise`, which RxJS v5 has *built-in support for*. Most operators that expect an observable can consume Promises as-is (like `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, etc). But often you'll want to apply Rx operators to the Promise before passing it along to the rest of your Epic, so you'll often want to wrap the Promise inside an Observable.

**You can wrap a Promise into an Observable with `Observable.from(promise)`**

Here's an example where I fetch for a user, request the JSON response, then wrap the promise in an observable:

```js
const api = {
  fetchUser: id => {
    const request = fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
      .then(response => response.json());
    return Observable.from(request);
  }
};
```

You can then consume that in your Epic and apply any operators you want:

```
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      api.fetchUser(action.payload) // This returns our Observable wrapping the Promise
        .map(payload => ({ type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED, payload }))
    );
```

Here's a JSBin with this working example: https://jsbin.com/fuwaguk/edit?js,output

---

If you have control over the API code, ideally you would use `Observable.ajax` (or any other Observable-based AJAX utils) because Promises cannot be cancelled. (as of this writing)

Comment: Thank you, Jay, for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Did small adjustment to @jayphelps in order to get that code work for me. Hope this helps to save someone's time.

```
import { FETCH_USER } from './actions'
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable'
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { from } from 'rxjs'

const fetchUserEpic = action$ => {
    return action$.pipe(
        ofType(FETCH_USER),
        mergeMap((action = { user: 'redux-observable' }) => {
            const getRequest = (user) => {
                const request = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                return from(request)
            }

            return getRequest(action.user).pipe(
               map(payload => ({ type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED, payload }))
            )
        })
    )
}
```