# Implementing Auto-Save in React-Redux-Firebase App using Redux-Observable

Tags: firebase, react-redux, rxjs5, redux-thunk, redux-observable

I am implementing auto-save for a react-redux-firebase side project using redux-observable. Currently I have a updateFretboardEpic that is responding to any actions that modify a Fretboard component currently possessing a reference (firebaseKey) to the Firebase database. After 1 second debounce, updateFretboard should save the new state of the component to Firebase.

```
import {
  ADD_STRING,
  REMOVE_STRING,
  INC_STR_PITCH,
  DEC_STR_PITCH,
  ADD_FRET,
  REMOVE_FRET,
  UPDATE_FRETBOARD
} from '../actions/action-types';

import {
  updateFretboard
} from '../actions/fretboard-actions';

export const updateFretboardEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.ofType(
      ADD_STRING,
      REMOVE_STRING,  
      INC_STR_PITCH,
      DEC_STR_PITCH,
      ADD_FRET,
      REMOVE_FRET
    )
    .filter(() => store.getState().fretboard.firebaseKey !== undefined)
    .debounceTime(1000)
    .map(() => updateFretboard(
      store.getState().fretboard.fretboardData,
      store.getState().fretboard.firebaseKey
    ));
};
```

However, I am currently getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    at Object.performAction (<anonymous>:3:2312)
    at liftAction (<anonymous>:2:27846)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:2:31884)
    at bundle.ff2509b….js:9896
    at SafeSubscriber.dispatch [as _next] (vendor.ff2509b….js:51341)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (bundle.ff2509b….js:392)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (bundle.ff2509b….js:339)
    at Subscriber._next (bundle.ff2509b….js:279)
    at Subscriber.next (bundle.ff2509b….js:243)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (bundle.ff2509b….js:6579)
```

Prior to implementing redux-observable, updateFretboard was using Redux-Thunk to dispatch an action:

```
export function updateFretboard(fretboardData, firebaseKey = undefined) {
  return dispatch => { fretboards.child(firebaseKey).update(fretboardData); };
}
```

Using that as it stands with redux-observable will produce the error without any auto-save. Instead of returning a thunk, I changed it to this:

```
export function updateFretboard(fretboardData, firebaseKey = undefined) {
  return fretboards.child(firebaseKey).update(fretboardData);
}
```

Interestingly, updateFretboardEpic will auto-save for the first action in the stream, return the error, and will not auto-save for any subsequent actions thereafter. updateFretboard does not currently flow through any of my reducers (it is only responsible for passing new state to Firebase), although I may choose in the future to receive a promise to know when the save occurred and pass it through my reducers.

I am new to RxJS/redux-observable, so I suspect there is a better way of doing this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using redux-observable without any other side effect middleware (like redux-thunk) means all actions you dispatch must be plain old JavaScript objects--that includes anything your epics emits.

It's not clear what `updateFretboard()` returns, except that is probably isn't a POJO action; it's whatever `fretboards.child(firebaseKey).update(fretboardData)` returns.

If instead of emitting an action, you actually meant to just perform that as a side effect but ignore its return value entirely, you would use something like the [`do()` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do), which is used to make a side effect without actually modifying the next'd values. You could then combine that with the [`ignoreElements()` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-ignoreElements) to prevent your epic from emitting anything ever.

```
export const updateFretboardEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.ofType(
      ADD_STRING,
      REMOVE_STRING,  
      INC_STR_PITCH,
      DEC_STR_PITCH,
      ADD_FRET,
      REMOVE_FRET
    )
    .filter(() => store.getState().fretboard.firebaseKey !== undefined)
    .debounceTime(1000)
    .do(() => updateFretboard(
      store.getState().fretboard.fretboardData,
      store.getState().fretboard.firebaseKey
    ))
    .ignoreElements();
};
```

Keep in mind that by using `ignoreElements()` this particular epic will **never** emit anything (though it will still propagate errors/complete). It becomes basically "readonly".

If you didn't use `ignoreElements()`, your epic would actually re-emit the same action it matched, causing unwanted recursion.

---

You might also find it easier to invert control of what gets saved and what doesn't. Instead of having to maintain a list of actions that should trigger an autosave, you could instead have actions have some sort of property that your epic listens for to know to save.

e.g.

```
// Listens for actions with `autosave: true`
export const updateFretboardEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.filter(action => action.autosave)
    // etc...
};

// e.g.
store.dispatch({
  type: ADD_STRING,
  autosave: true
});
```

Adjust convention to your apps needs, accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jay! Apologies for not being explicit about what fretboards.child(firebaseKey).update(fretboardData) returns. It returns a promise, so I ended up turning that into an observable and mapping that to a new action with a boolean indicating the success of the autosave. Your solution also worked but wouldn't emit a success event as you mentioned, which is why I went the promise-based route.

Comment: Like the answer below, I'd reccomend doing 'Observablr.from()' on the updateFretboard

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem (thanks Jay for pointing me in the right direction!).

In my question, I wasn't explicit about what fretboards.child(firebaseKey).update(fretboardData) actually is.
fretboards.child(firebaseKey) is a reference to the particular child
of fretboards with the specified firebase key (the full path would be firebase.database().ref('fretboards').child(firebaseKey)). Firebase database utilizes a Promise-based API, so update will return a Promise:

```
const updateRequest=fretboards.child(firebaseKey).update(fretboardData)
  .then(function(result) {
    // do something with result
  }, function(err) {
    // handle error
  });
```

Borrowing from another answer Jay gave on a different post ([Use fetch instead of ajax with redux-observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589383/use-fetch-instead-of-ajax-with-redux-observable)), I came up with the following solution:

```
import { fretboards } from '../firebase-config.js';
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'; 

import {
  ADD_STRING,
  REMOVE_STRING,
  INC_STR_PITCH,
  DEC_STR_PITCH,
  ADD_FRET,
  REMOVE_FRET,
  AUTOSAVE_FRETBOARD
} from '../actions/action-types';

function autoSaveFretboard(fretboardData, firebaseKey = undefined) {
  let autoSaveFretboardRequest = fretboards.child(firebaseKey)
    .update(fretboardData).then(function(result) {
      // won't need to pass result through reducers, so return
      // true to indicate save was successful
      return true;
    }, function(err) {
      // log error and return false in case of autosave failure
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  return Rx.Observable.from(autoSaveFretboardRequest);
}

export const autoSaveFretboardEpic = (action$, store) => {
  return action$.ofType(
      ADD_STRING,
      REMOVE_STRING,  
      INC_STR_PITCH,
      DEC_STR_PITCH,
      ADD_FRET,
      REMOVE_FRET
    )
    .filter(() => store.getState().fretboard.firebaseKey !== undefined)
    .debounceTime(750)
    .mergeMap(() => autoSaveFretboard(
        store.getState().fretboard.fretboardData,
        store.getState().fretboard.firebaseKey
      ).map((res) => (
        { type: AUTOSAVE_FRETBOARD, success: res }
      ))
    );
};
```

Based on whether the auto-save promise is successful or not, a boolean will be returned to indicate the success of the save, which is mapped to a new action AUTOSAVE_FRETBOARD which I can pass along to my reducers.

As Jay pointed out in that prior post, promises can't be cancelled. Since the Firebase database is implemented as a Promise-based API, I don't really see a way around that. At the moment, I can't think of a reason why I would want to cancel the auto-save, so I'm happy with this solution!