# How to handle `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when using Observable.from(<Promise>) and catching error in the Observable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-observable

I am using `redux-observable` together with `isomorphic-fetch` to handle http requests in my `React` app. I am favouring this combination over using rxjs' `ajax` because I am testing with `Jest` - which runs tests in `Node.js`- and want to intercept http requests with `nock`. See this related question: [Use fetch instead of ajax with redux-observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589383/use-fetch-instead-of-ajax-with-redux-observable).

So here is the problem: I get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` together with a scary: `DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.` because I am not catching my promise rejections directly but rather leave that to the Observable:

```
// apiModule.js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

const api = {
  getSomething: () => {
    const request = fetch('http://some-api/')
      .then(res => catchError(res)) // throwing an Error here if not response.ok
      .then(res => res.json())

    return Observable.from(request)
  }
}
```

Then in the epic:

```
// myReduxModule.js
import {api} from './apiModule.js'

const getSomethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType(GET_SOMETHING)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      api
        .getSomething()
        .map(response => getSomethingSucceeded(response))
        .catch(error => logError(error)) // error is handled here!
    )
```

So the promise rejection is handled in the Observable but not directly!

Any suggestions how to avoid the warning (and a possible future terminate with non-zero exit code) in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From now on, every time you have a promise and you call the `then`, you **must** also implement the `catch`. Also in your tests.

```
 const request = fetch('http://some-api/')
      .then(res => catchError(res))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => catchError(res)) // <= here you should implement the catch
```